# What setIsSubscribed() function does when called on a Mage::getModel('customer/customer') object!

Tags: magento-1.7

I am working on newsletter subscription bug. In this case the subscription status is always becoming not subscribed even when the customer chooses subscription. There are two cases.

*Bug-1:* When a customer creates account and opts or don't opt for subscription,  his/her status is coming not subscribed.

*Bug-2:* There is edit option for subscription but that is also not working, customers are not able to change subscription status. If they are old customers and their status is subscribed, it remains subscribed - even when they edit to unsubscribe.

What I dug is that Magento provides module for newsletter subscription, and data for subscription goes into the table `newsletter_subscriber`.For first scenario nothing is going into this table for newly created accounts. For second case after editing subscription status `ManageController/saveAction` of newsletter module is called which calls `setIsSubscribed()` function on `Mage::getModel('customer/session')` object.

But there is no definition of `setIsSubscribed()` function. That means magic function is called. I am trying to solve these bugs. So I gave definition of `setIsSubscription()` into `local/namespace/customer/model/customer` and was able to solve bug number 2. But for bug-1 please someone give some suggestions and also please suggest if I did right thing for bug-2.

Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newsletter subscription is done via events inside the module `Mage_Newsletter`. These events can be found by looking into the file `resources/magento/src/store/app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/etc/config.xml`.

The main things to look for are the events `customer_save_after` and `customer_delete_after`.

**customer_save_after**

This will call `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Observer::subscribeCustomer`. Here the customer object is taken from the event and passed to `Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribeCustomer($customer);`.

Now this function will check a few things against the customer object but in the end should update the newsletter status for the given customer.

**customer_delete_after**

This will call `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Observer::customerDeleted`. Here the subscriber object will be loaded by email address and then deleted.

```
$subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')
    ->loadByEmail($observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()->getEmail());
if($subscriber->getId()) {
    $subscriber->delete();
}
```

My guess is that either these events have been turned off for your system or they are not getting the right information because of a local or template change. You best bet for debugging would be to enable xdebug and set through these events to see what and why things are not working.

Comment: Thank you David thats all I needed, Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribeCustomer($customer); is commented in Mage_Newsletter_Model_Observer::subscribeCustomer and thats why nothing is going into newsletter_subscriber table, thank you so much :)